# How to load image data for regression with keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I already have read now several tutorials that are giving instructions of how to import images for classification with Keras. As far as I see, all tutorials are just describing a multi-class scenario (e.g. cat/dog class.). These approaches don`t apply to my problem.

I want to do a regression that takes the images as input and returns images as output.
My question: **How would I easily pass the image data to Keras, if there is no classification but regression?**

With each pair of given input and output training data, I can't find an easy import from:

```
├── input_data
│   ├── input0.png
|   ├── input1.png
|   └── ...
└── output_data
    ├── output0.png
    ├── output1.png
    └── ...
```

to this point:

```
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(inputs, outputs, test_size=0.2, shuffle= True)
```

*What I have already tried:*

1. The Keras [flow_from_directory](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdirectory-method) method seems almost perfect and offers nice functionalities, but it only applies for classification data that is sorted in subdirectories.
2. Secondly, there is this [image import function,](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img) given by Tensorflow.

   ```
   from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
   img = load_img('img.png') 
   x = img_to_array(img)
   ```

It is also straight forward as far as I know, there is only the possibility to open single images and not whole directories. This might be helpful if iterating over the whole directory, but since Keras has those nice **preprocessing features**, I am curious to know if there is a keras-like way. So my question:

**Is there any comortable way to import large image datasets for regression?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no specific function in `Keras` to load *all* images as a dataset. However, you can accomplish this by using a combination of `os.walk()` and `Image.open()`, something like the following would load all images into a list in one go:

```
import os
from PIL import Image  # or you can use the keras one to load images
def load_dataset(top_dir="input_data"):
    images_dataset = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top_dir):
        for name in files:
            # print(os.path.join(root, name))
            img = np.array(Image.open(os.path.join(root, name)))
            images_dataset.append(img)
    return images_dataset
```

Comment: Okay thanks - this is a manual way with PIL that is working. I hoped to use the preprocessing features of Keras but it seems that I have to do this by hand.

Comment: @moosehead42 As I said, I am not aware of any Keras-ish built-in function to do it. However, the above function can be placed in a  `utility` module and called directly from that file *as if it was from Keras API*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use image_dataset_from_directory function from keras.utils